# Is there a way to fetch data directly from simplexmlelement object?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have the following simplexmlelement object. Unlike other answers in which we have the actual xml, I do not have that XML. Still I need to fetch the values directly from my simplexmlelement object. Is there a way??

Below is xml data

```
$quote= SimpleXMLElement Object (
[0]=> 1009
 )
```

I have to fetch the 0th index element value .

Note: I have been given access to only this XML object. Unlike some solutions I do not have the actual XML. I tried using 
echo $quote[0] 
But it gives me error as unidentified object. Then I tried using foreach loop.but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example

```
<?php
  $note = '<channel>
             <title>What For Dinner</title>
             <link>http://menu.example.com/</link>
             <description>Choose what to eat tonight.</description>
          </channel>';
  $xml=simplexml_load_string($note);
  print_r($xml->title);
  foreach ($xml->title as $key => $value) {}
  echo $value;
?>
```

In your code you can use

```
foreach ($quote as $key => $value) {}
  echo $value;
```

https://eval.in/527404

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work...the thing is that your answer would be correct if I get the simplexmlelement object after I use simple_XML_string on original XML and then derive the simplexmlelement object. But if we do start directly from simplexmlelement object , then your solution fails

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object (
[Max]=>100
[Min]=> 0
[Volume]=> 1218
)
 )

i have only this object given to me. I do not have any XML code. I am supposed to capture individual values from this object

Comment: Yes...a third party gives me the xmlelememt object in the variable $quote

Comment: You are making an XML again...I don't have the XML...some one wrote the XML and did simplxml_load. Then the object formed was assigned to me in the form of a variable $quote. Now I am supposed to fetch the values. I do not have any XML .

Comment: this is examply to understand, you can directly start from foreach.

Comment: can you update your question , what exactly you are doing and what error you are getting.